# How to make a realtime preview of a web-based text editor?

Tags: javascript

Well, just like this Stackoverflow editor.
Furthermore, how to do this with additional js loaded? (like realtime math preview on math.stackexchange)

Explicitly, what I want now explicitly is that how to refresh instantly.

Now what I can come up with is

```
show(){
    var text=document.getElementById("preview");
    var input=document.getElementById("inputArea").value;
    text.innerHTML=input;
}
<textarea id="inputArea">fd</textarea>
<p id="preview"></p>
<button onclick="show()">show</button>
```

But this clearly is not realtime. Maybe it is possible to add a timer and execute 'show()' every, say 0.1 seconds. But this too is not wise I think.

Is there any native HTML or javascript method that can achieve this?

Comment: your question is too vague and general. Try something by yourself and post some code to have an answer

Comment: @Gianmarco, I have edited to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Here, Have a look at Aloha Editor.

http://www.aloha-editor.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function show(v){
    document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = v;
}
</script>
<textarea id="inputArea" onkeyup="show(this.value)"></textarea>
<p id="preview"></p>
```

you can even do it with out a JS snippet:

```
<textarea id="inputArea" onkeyup="document.getElementById('preview').innerHTML=this.value"></textarea>
<p id="preview"></p>
```

Comment: yes i didn't notice that you need it to be onkey up because i thought it's only about the syntax that your code was having